# React: Persistant Props Without Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React-Router with React, and am trying to pass a list from component to another. I am console logging whether or not the data is undefined once I click shortlist and I immediately get false (meaning there is data), but when I navigate to the page I get true (meaning there is not data there).

Here is my app component

```
class App extends Component {

      constructor(){
        super()


    this.state = {
      applications: [{
        "id":1, "name":"John Smith", "position":"Server", "applied":"03/15/16", "experience":2, "availability":{
        "M":2, "T":2, "W":1, "Th":2, "F":1, "S":0,
        "Su":0 }, "questions":[
        {
        "text":"Have you ever been convicted of a felony?", "answer":"No" } ] }, 
        {
        "id":2, "name":"Jane Smith", "position":"Cook", "applied":"02/08/16", "experience":4, "availability":{
        "M":1, "T":1, "W":1, "Th":1, "F":0, "S":0, "Su":0 }, "questions":[
        {
        "text":"Have you ever been convicted of a felony?", "answer":"Yes" } ] }, 
        {
        "id":3, "name":"David Jessup", "position":"Chef", "applied":"03/08/16", "experience":2, "availability":{
        "M":2, "T":2, "W":2, "Th":2, "F":2,
        "S":0, "Su":0 }, "questions":[
        {
        "text":"Are you authorized to work in the United States?", "answer":"Yes" } ] }, 
        {
        "id":4, "name":"Clay van Schalkwijk", "position":"Cook", "applied":"03/08/16", "experience":1, "availability":{
        "M":1, "T":0, "W":1, "Th":0, "F":1, "S":0, "Su":0 }, "questions":[
        {
        "text":"Are you authorized to work in the United States?", "answer":"Yes" } ] }
        ],
        searchField:'',
        saved:[],
    }
  }
  render() {
           return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='main'>
      <Sidebar/>
      <div className="App">
      <Search searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
      </div>
      <Switch>

        <Route exact path='/' render={()=> <Applications props={this.state}/>} />
        <Route path='/shortlistedApplicants' render={()=> <ShortlistedApplicants props={this.state.saved}/>}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my applications page that displays all of the applicants. Each has a button that I can click that can add to another array in state(ignore below where it says state, I will change to props)

```
class Applications extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
               }
    onFavorite = applicant => {
      const { saved } = this.state; 
      const index = saved.indexOf(applicant);

      if(index === -1) {
       this.setState({
        saved: [...saved, applicant],
       })

      } else {
        saved.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({saved});
      }
    }
    onSearchChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        searchField:event.target.value
      })
    }

    onRemove = applicant => {
      const {saved} = this.state;
      saved.splice(saved.indexOf(applicant), 1);
      this.setState({
        saved
      })
    }
    render(){
           return(
               <div>
               <Header state={this.state} searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
            <div className='scroll'>
           <table className='app-table'>
                       <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Exp.</th>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th>Availability</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    {this.state.applications.map((app) => {
                        return(
                            <tr>
                            <td>{app.name}</td>
                         <td>{app.position}</td>
                         <td>{app.experience}</td>
                         <td>{app.questions[0].text} 
                         <p>
                         {app.questions[0].answer} </p>
                         </td>
                         <td><strong>M:</strong>{app.availability.M}, 
             <strong>T:</strong> {app.availability.T},
             <strong>W:</strong> {app.availability.W},
             <strong>Th:</strong> {app.availability.Th},
             <strong>F:</strong> {app.availability.F},
             <strong>S:</strong> {app.availability.S},
             <strong>Su:</strong> {app.availability.Su}</td>
     <td>Applied On: {app.applied}</td>
     <td><Btn onFavorite={() => this.onFavorite(app)} shortlist={this.state.saved.includes(app)}/></td>
                        </tr> )})}
                    </table>
                    </div>
           <ShortlistedApplicants saved={this.state.saved} onRemove={this.onRemove}/>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Applications;
```

Lastly here is the shortlisted page where I want to map through the
saved array in app then display. However I keep losing state when
navigating here

```
const ShortlistedApplicants = ({saved, onRemove}) => {
    let applicants;
    console.log(saved===undefined)
    if(saved === undefined){
        applicants = <div>Nothing to Show</div>
        } 
        if(saved) {
            applicants = saved.map((app) => {
                return(
                    <table className='app-table'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>{app.name}</td>
                        <td>{app.position}</td>
                        <td>{app.experience}</td>
                        <td>{app.questions[0].text}
                        {app.questions[0].answer}
                        </td>
                        <td>M:{app.availability.M}, 
            T:{app.availability.T},
            W:{app.availability.W},
            Th:{app.availability.Th},
            F:{app.availability.F},
            S:{app.availability.S},
            Su:{app.availability.Su}</td>
    <td>Applied On: {app.applied}</td>
    <td><button onClick={() => onRemove(app)}>X</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                )
            })

    }
    return(
        <div className='shortlisted'><h1 className='shortlisted'>Shortlisted Applicants Page</h1>
              <hr style={{borderTop:"black 5px solid"}}/>
              {applicants}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShortlistedApplicants;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?

It has been reworked and is included in React v16+. It is a nice lightweight way to handle state management.

Comment: This... yeah I was gonna suggest using the context API in React. The data flow is weird. He should look into that.

Comment: Indeed. The data flow can be tricky at first, but easier to adopt than Redux. @Berheet Make sure to set up your provider at the top of your component tree. Any child can access the state using a consumer. The React documentation I posted is pretty thorough. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing Props to `App?`

What you get back when you just pass the this.state object in one of your props in App.js?

I think the usage is wrong. You might want to be specific what data you need to pass in from parent component.

Also are you importing the proptype library anywhere?

Comment: I am not familiar with proptype or its usages. But the flow is essentially all of my state and data is managed in app, and props are passed to applications (which has the shortlist component there too and shows the saved array but I want to move that component to its own page.

Comment: you need to do like `import Proptype from 'prop-types'` and have the library installed using `npm install prop-types --save-dev`

Comment: @Berheet Also look into context types. Context type will allow you to use the App and the other components required.